# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception with struts2 and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

i face a problem from yesterday 
it is my first app in struts2 and eclipse
this exception

```
2014-09-03 07:15:22.146:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
Sep 03, 2014 7:15:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Sep 03, 2014 7:15:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Sep 03, 2014 7:15:27 AM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Hussein/workspace/HelloWorldStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer class:org.apache.struts2.components.PortletUrlRenderer - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Hussein/workspace/HelloWorldStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/portlet/PortletMode
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:235)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.portlet.PortletMode
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:392)
    at runjettyrun.ProjectClassLoader.loadClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:89)
    ... 23 more
2014-09-03 07:15:27.982:WARN::failed struts2: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Hussein/workspace/HelloWorldStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
2014-09-03 07:15:27.982:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@7dee05dc{/HelloWorldStruts2,C:\Users\Hussein\workspace\HelloWorldStruts2\WebContent}
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Hussein/workspace/HelloWorldStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
```

i uploaded this project folder,
i hope to find any one to help me to find why this app doesn't run,
so sad and angry of this problem, bcz i tried a lot of solutions and no hope
also i'm sorry if the file size is large (19mb) but it's bcz i attached all jar's with the project

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjep4txkbnjpevd/HelloWorldStruts2.rar?dl=0

Comment: Do you want to use portlet plugin in your application? If not remove this jar.

Comment: And most of the other ones. 107 jars ? Most of them conflicting ? C'mon...

Comment: no i didn't want to want to use any plugins it's just helloWorld app, also i deleted all files unless the basic 10 jar's

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that i missed the file "commons-lang3-x.x.x.jar"
and when i tried to solve i added all the files which made conflict problem

so my advice 
use just jar's that you need

and the files that you need for helloWorld app is

```
commons-fileupload-x.x.x.jar
commons-io-x.x.jar
commons-lang-x.x.jar
commons-lang3-x.x.x.jar
commons-logging-x.x.x.jar
commons-logging-api-x.x.jar
freemarker-x.x.x.jar
javassist-3.x.x.GA.jar
ognl-3.x.x.jar
struts2-core-x.x.x.x.jar
xwork-core-2.x.x.x.jar
```

my best wishes :D
and thanx indeed for you